# Bubble sorting with strcpy

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

So I have an an example `array`:

```
char* drivers[10] = {"Mark", "Jacob", "Andre", "Thomas", "Hellboy"};
```

And an `srand` function that generates random "Lap times" for each driver and stores the laptime to an `array`:

```
float lap_time[10];
```

I need to sort them respectively to get the "Top 1" and "Last 1", I'm thinking of bubble sort but it doesn't seem to work like it should. It generates an error. Bus fault or something similar. If I remove the `strcpy()` part, it works just as fine. But something somewhere related to `strcpy()` has an error.

This is just the sorting function, everything else works perfectly. When `strcpy()` is added with `char tmp[]` array then this function crashes.

`printf()` for this function works. Just problem with getting my `strcpy()` to work.

Sorting:

```
#define maks 10; 

int Fastestdriver(char* drivers[], float lap_times[], char tmp[maks])
{
    int i, j, a;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i+1 ; j < 10 ; ++j)
        {
            if (lap_time[i] < lap_time[j])
            {
                a =  lap_time[i];
                lap_time[i] = lap_time[j];
                lap_time[j] = a;
                strcpy(tmp, drivers[i]);
                strcpy(drivers[i], drivers[j]);
                strcpy(drivers[j], tmp);

            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change to `char *tmp = drivers[i]; drivers[i] = drivers[j]; drivers[j] = tmp;`

Comment: There should be no need to use `strcpy` here. Just shuffle around the pointers to your strings.

Comment: How does this even compile? `#define maks 10;` should not have a semi-colon.

Comment: define maks 10 it was my error, there is no colon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared and initialized like this -

```
char* drivers[10]={"Mark", "Jacob", "Andre", "Thomas", "Hellboy"};
```

`drivers[0]` ,`drivers[1]` are string literals (*constants -should not be modified* ) and in function you try to modify them with `strcpy` ,therefore this problem-

```
strcpy(drivers[i], drivers[j]);
strcpy(drivers[j], tmp);
```

You can just assign pointers to each other -

```
char *tmp;                 // declare char * not char [] 
...
tmp=drivers[i];
drivers[i]=drivers[j];
drivers[j]=drivers[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

drivers is an array with ten elements. The elements of "drivers" are pointers. They point to small nameless static arrays, for example "Mark" points to an array with five chars M, a, r, k, and \0.

You can just exchange these pointers.

What you are trying with strcpy: For example, "Mark" is a pointer to an array with five chars, "Jacob" is a pointer to an array of six chars. You can't exchange the cars with strcpy, because "Jacob" doesn't fit where "Mark" is stored. And moreover, these arrays are likely read-only, so even if everything had the same length, any attempt to change these arrays would crash.